# Unable to parallelize a function with multiple arguments in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mclapply

I tried to parallelize a simple function which adds two numbers and prints the result in `R` using `mclapply` in the library `parallel`. This is my code :

```
library(doParallel)
t = list(list(1,1),list(2,2),list(3,3))
f <- function (a,b){
    print(a + b)
}
mclapply(t,f)
```

But it returns the error :

```
Warning message in mclapply(t, f):
“all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code”
```

```
[[1]]
[1] "Error in print(a + b) : argument \"b\" is missing, with no default\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in print(a + b): argument "b" is missing, with no default>

[[2]]
[1] "Error in print(a + b) : argument \"b\" is missing, with no default\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in print(a + b): argument "b" is missing, with no default>

[[3]]
[1] "Error in print(a + b) : argument \"b\" is missing, with no default\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in print(a + b): argument "b" is missing, with no default>
```

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

I tried to search how to run a function with multiple arguments in parallel, but no answers was found.

Comment: `mclapply` is part of the **parallel** package; the **doParallel** package has nothing to do with this, i.e. use `library(parallel)` in your example here

Comment: FYI, you can easily reproduce your problem by using a regular `lapply()`.  They you'll get `Error in print(a + b) : argument "b" is missing, with no default`.  Thus, the problem has nothing to do with the **parallel** package either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mclapply` is calling the function for each element of the list which itself is a list. Therefore each time you call the function you pass it a list and nothing else. You need to unpack the the list in the function:

```
library(doParallel)
t = list(list(1,1),list(2,2),list(3,3))
f <- function (a){
  print(a[[1]] + a[[2]])
}
mclapply(t,f)
```